# SQLite table name length limit

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using SQLite with Python and I have the following simple code copied from the SQLite tutorials:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('references.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE refs
            (author text, title text, year int)''')

c.execute('''INSERT INTO refs VALUES
            ('author1', 'title1', 2014)''')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This works well. However, whenever I try to set the table name to "references":

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE refs
            (author text, title text, year int)''')
```

I get this error:

```
line 7, in <module> (author text, title text, year int)''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "references": syntax error
```

I have checked other posts and I see there should not be a problem with the maximum length.

http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/20054.html
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

What is wrong here then?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REFERENCES is a reserved word, used in table declarations, so it makes sense that you would not be able to use it in a table declaration.

Comment: Wow I have never suspeceted it was because the name itself. Thank you!